# Karate Robot does not list my application in list printed by "* print robot.allWindows" which was forked by script only

Tags: karate

Karate Robot does not list my application in list printed by "* print robot.allWindows" which was forked by script only.

- karate.fork('C:\Program Files\PNC\PNC.exe')
- robot { highlight: true, highlightDuration: 500, autoClose: false }
- print robot.allWindows

Comment: I checked that even Postman windows application is also not getting detected by Karate Robot

Comment: well, sorry. nothing that comes to my mind. please try your best to do some research and contribute code if possible. UI automation is hard and can depend on OS / jdk versions etc. if the window does not show up in `inspect.exe` there is nothing karate can do. try installing it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#windows-tips

Answer (score 0):

Try your best to do some research and contribute code if possible. UI automation is hard and can depend on OS / JDK versions etc.

If the window does not show up in `inspect.exe` there is nothing Karate can do.

Tips on installing `inspect.exe` can be found here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#windows-tips

Comment: Even for Chrome, the title is  empty ' ' due to which Chrome is also not getting selected by Karate Robot

Comment: @Ashish I have no further comments to make. it seems to work fine for many others. you are welcome to switch to some other framework